# For a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $\alpha >0$, prove that $A^{\dagger}A^{\alpha}=A^{\alpha}A^{\dagger}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> For a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $\alpha >0$, prove that $A^{\dagger}A^{\alpha}=A^{\alpha}A^{\dagger}$.
>
> (Here $A^{\dagger}$ is the Moore Penrose inverse of $A$. )

$$\begin{align}
A^{\dagger}A^{\alpha} & =A^{\dagger}AA^{\dagger}A^{\alpha}\\
                      & = (A^{\dagger}A)^{T}(A^T)^{\dagger}(A^T)^{\alpha}\\
                      & = (A^{\alpha}(A^{\dagger})^2 A)^T
\end{align}$$

I don't know how to continue in order to obtain the result.

Comment: No further assumptions on the matrix $A$, for instance being positive-semidefinite? ... just to make $A^\alpha$ meaningful also for non-natural
$\alpha$.

Comment: @Hanno $A$ need not be necessarily positive semidefiniite since the matrices are considered over complex numbers. Also $A^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$ is defined in the same way we define such powers for natural numbers.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$omplexity will not help you; if the exponent $\alpha$ is fractional then you need more, that is less (i.e., a less general $A$). Try to make sense out of $\:\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^{0.5}$.